# cv2 and Flask, window does not open after destroywindows function

Tags: python, flask, opencv, ftplib

I have a problem, i create a script for saving a photo using cv2 when a get request exists on Flask api (get), the image is send a ftp server and send the name the file in json.

The problem is that the first request works fine but when send second request the app it stays loading all the time, not send error and the frame does open, i think what cv2 saving other instance or the process destroywindow is not finished.[image]

This my code and the process is commented.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import numpy as np
import ftplib as ftp
from cv2 import cv2
import datetime
import os



app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/image')
def get_images():

    user = "user"
    password = "pass"
    server = ftp.FTP()

    server.connect('1.1.1.1', 21)
    try:
        print("Logging in...")
        server.login(user, password)
    except: 
        return jsonify({ "error": "error: not acces ftp " }), 500

    try:
        cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        if not cam.isOpened():
            raise NameError('Just a Dummy Exception, write your own')
    except cv2.error as e:
        print("cv2.error:", e)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception:", e)
    else:
        print(cam.isOpened())

    try:
        cv2.namedWindow("test")
    except cv2.error as e:
        print("cv2.error:", e)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception:", e)
    else:
        print("no problem reported")


    while(cam.isOpened()):
        retval, frame = cam.read()

        if retval != True:
            raise ValueError("Can't read frame")
            break

        print("cam read")
        cv2.imshow("test", frame)
        print("show image")
        now=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
        img_name = "opencv_frame_{}.png".format(now)
        cv2.imwrite(img_name, frame)
        print("{} written!".format(img_name))
        with open(img_name, 'rb') as f:  
            try:
                server.storbinary('STOR '+img_name, f)
                print("save image on FTP Server")
                print("Delete Local image")
                os.remove(img_name)
                break
            except ftp.all_errors as e:
                return json.dumps({ "error": "Error writing ftp server:"+e}), 500 
                break
    print("show image")
    cam.release()
    cv2.destroyWindow("test")
    server.quit()
    server.close()
    data=[{'image':img_name}]
    return jsonify(data) 

app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

Comment: You shouldn't open GUI windows in web applications. Also you should not open the video device inside the view. You will get troubles when there are multiple requests at the same time.

Comment: What do you recommend me?